# Show that $rank(A) \ngeq \frac{[tr(A)]^2 }{tr(A^2)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank, trace

here $A$ is a Hermitian square matrix.

A few thoughts on the problem:

We know the matrix $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable, so $A = PDP^{-1}$ for some unitary matrix $P$.

Since this is the only assumption given in the problem, the above factorization is probably crucial, but I do not know how to utilize it.

So, I  am instead trying some brute force calculations on the RHS of the inequality, with not much success.

For instance, expanding the numerator in the RHS and then regrouping terms, I see that

$$[\operatorname{tr}(A)]^2 = \sum_i^n a_{ii}^2 + 2\sum_{i \ne j}a_{ii}a_{jj}$$

I am not sure how to expand the denominator, $tr(A^2)$, without more information about $A$.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does >/= mean <?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix $D$, then $A$ and $D$ will have the same rank and trace.  Moreover, $A^2$ will be similar to $D^2$.

Alternatively, note that since $A$ is Hermitian,
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2
$$

---

Suppose without loss of generality that $A$ is diagonal of the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ &\ddots \\ && \lambda_r \\
&&&0 \\
&&&& \ddots\\
&&&&& 0}
$$
where the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ are real and non-zero.

Note that rank$(A) = r$.  Now, the tricky bit: we apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.  We have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A)^2 =
\left[\sum_{j=1}^r\lambda_j\right]^2 = \\
|(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r)\cdot(1,\dots,1)|^2 \leq\\
\|(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r)\|^2 \|(1,\dots,1)\|^2 = \\
\left[\sum_{j=1}^r\lambda_j^2\right] \cdot r = 
\operatorname{rank}(A) \operatorname{trace}(A^2)
$$
The result follows.

Comment: I definitely know your first sentence - that rank and trace are similarity invariants.  But your second line is interesting...and I totally missed that...thanks so much, let me see what I can do now...@Omnomnomnom,

Comment: right...@Omnomnomnom, I don't understand that brute force calculation of $tr(A^2)$ ... how do you do that?  without information on the entries of A ... sorry, sounds naive, I know...the numerator computation was straightforward, though...just expansion and regrouping terms...can't say the same about $tr(A^2)$, though...

Comment: hmm...$tr(AA^*) = tr(A^*A) = tr(A^2)$ ...

Comment: @user303506 it's all in the summation notation.  Note that the $i,i$ entry of the matrix $A^2$ is given by
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}a_{ji}
$$

Comment: @user303506 or what you said, which is how I really did it

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, so I worked out your calculations of $tr(A^2)$ and agree with you; nice usage of the conjugate-transpose of the entries.  So now I'm looking at the quotient of sums on the RHS of the inequality...and can't seem to notice any relation to the rank of $A$ ... can you offer another hint?  Or perhaps now is the time to use the factorization of $A$ ... and looking at the diagonal matrix that it is similar to...

Comment: OOh, I wonder if this is really an eigenvalues problem....trace = sum of eigenvalues...A hermitian has real eigenvalues...

Comment: And $tr(A^2) = tr(D^2)$ ...would be positive-semi-definite... @omnomnomnom,

Comment: Start by trying to show that the inequality holds if $A$ is a real diagonal matrix. The left side is just the number of non-zero entries.

Comment: Thanks for the extra hint...@omnomnomnom...it's really time to use the factorization of A...let's see here...

Comment: hi @omnomnomnom, i think I am almost there... I have $\frac{tr(D) tr(D)}{ tr(D^2)}  \le \frac{tr(D) tr(D)}{ tr(D)} = tr(D)$.  Now I want to say $tr(D) \le rank (D)$... what do you think?  Regarding the last inequality...I still don't see a relation between the rank and trace of $A$...

Comment: in this approach, I have only used the assumption that $A$ is diagonalizable, but haven't used the *unitarily* diagonalizable assumption...maybe that is crucial... @omnomnomnom ...

Comment: Well, I can actually bound $tr(A)$ with $\sum \lambda_{max} = n* \lambda_{max}$ ... maybe there's some upper bound on eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix...

Comment: I'll edit in a full solution if I have time later

Comment: See my latest edit